# WPF BlurEffect Sluggish Performance and FPS

Tags: wpf, performance, effects

In my code i have multiple BlurEffects applied to multiple borders with code similar to the following in my OnRender method:

```
        var blurEffect = new BlurEffect();
        blurEffect.Radius = 5;
        blurEffect.RenderingBias = RenderingBias.Performance;
        blurEffect.KernelType = KernelType.Gaussian;
        blurEffect.Freeze();

        MainBorder.Effect = blurEffect;
```

However, when i apply this kind of effects to multiple elements i have noticed sluggish performance and a drop of FPS under 50. Adding more borders with effects makes it even worse.

Are there any performance tricks i can do or an alternative drawing method that i can use to get the same Blur effect on the border, but with better performance?

Comment: I'm currently looking for a similar solution :(